# Use variable to hold dataframe name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have four dataframes, df1, df2, df3, and df4. They are all formatted identically.

I would like to be able to store the dataframe name in a variable, and access that dataframe later. I can do the below, but this just copies the entire dataframe. Is there a way to do this without copying the whole dataframe?

```
chart.df <- df1
plot(chart.df$x, chart.df$y)
```

Note that this is just an example. I would like to do other things aside from just plotting.

Comment: You could do `plot(y ~ x, data = df_name)`.

Comment: Put the data frames in a named list: `list(df1 = df1,df2 = df2,df3 = df3,df4 = df4)`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm not looking to just do plotting, but rather pass the reference to a function, in general.

Comment: @joran - what does that accomplish?

Comment: You can refer to the data frame by it's name: `my_list[["df1"]]`. If you're trying to accomplish pass-by-reference semantics when writing R functions, though, then I would argue that you just shouldn't. If a function needs a data frame, pass it the data frame as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some circumstances, you can store the names of the data.frames as a character vector and then use `get()` to access the objects. In my experience @Joran's solution is more flexible as you can loop (or apply) through the list items in either by name or position depending on your application.